# Need explanation on asymptotic running time results for various functions

Tags: asymptotics

I did not understand few results from the book problem.

Here is the problem:
Indicate, for each pair of expressions (A, B) in the table below, whether A is
O, o, Ω, ω, Θ of B. Assume that k ≥ 1,  > 0, and c > 1 are constants.
And solution:
[image]

I am not sure

- why c. has all NO. How is this can even be the case?
- why e. has YES for Ω and Θ . Asymptotically $c^{lg(n)}$ grow faster than $n^{lg(c)}$, right? Why $n^{lg(c)}$ is not in o($c^{lg(n)}$) ?
- why f. has YES for  Ω and  Θ . It also seems that asymptotacally $lg(n^n)$ grows faster than $lg(n!)$ . Why $lg(n!)$ is not in o($lg(n^n)$) ?

Answer (score 1):

For c: due to $\sin n$ this function is unbounded, so there doesn't exist $c$ such that any of the order functions hold

For e: consider taking $n = e^t$

For f: use Stirling's formula or Euler-Maclaurin for $\sum_k \log k$, these functions are of the same order.

Comment: I still do not understand c part. Why is this function not exponential?

Comment: $n^{\sin n}$ is unbounded, i.e. it can take very small (e.g. $\frac{1}{1000}$) and very large (e.g. 1000) values infintely often due to $\sin n$ periodicity. Hence we can't find a constant for which the asymptotic ratio will hold